# hasOwnProperty() method

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am trying to understand the hasOwnProperty() method.. I understand that the method tests whether the object has an own property with a given name in the method. However, it returns **false** for inherited properties.

```js
var o = {
  name: 'Master',
  number: '117',
  last: 'Chief'
};

o.prototype = {
  planet: 'Halo'
};

for(var p in o) {
  if(!o.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
    continue;
  }
  console.log(p);
}
```

So, when I run this script that console returns "name","number","last", and "prototype" from o.prototype. Can someone give me an explanation why the script if returning inherited properties? I thought negating the method "hasOwnProperty()" would skip inherited properties.

Comment: This doesn't print "planet" so it's doing what you would expect.

Comment: Not reproducible. This code logs `name, number, last, prototype`, not `name, number, last, plant`. And the object only inherits from `Object.prototype`, which doesn't have any enumerable property (by default).

Comment: The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) has an article that explains this method very well. What you are _actually_ struggling with is the concepts surrounding Prototypical Inheritance, which is obvious by your failed attempt at using prototypes. Please, read [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects), and spend some time properly studying OOP in JavaScript.

Comment: Note that `o.prototype` is nothing special, just an oddly named property containing an object, as `o` is not a function constructor, but a literal

Comment: @Recon The code doesn't log what you claim it does. Please check your console and fix the post ...

Comment: @Recon But it ***doesn't*** log `planet` (or `plant`). It's not about the typo. Nothing at all starting with `plan*` shows up in the console when you run your example.

Comment: @Recon You didn't check the console ... Anyway, you don't have any inherited properties in your object, just these own properties: `name`, `number`, `last` and `prototype`. That's what you see in the console. Please re-read adeneo's comment, it's your answer.

Comment: @Teemu  How would you correct my script for it to work accordingly ? I was thinking that Object o would inherit from o.prototype.

Comment: An object literal only inherits from the Object() constructor. If you want inheritance you'll need constructor functions that create new instances with the `new` keyword etc.

Comment: `o.prototype` is just a regular property, it doesn't have anything to do with inheritance. Only functions have a meaningful `prototype` object. Please read the MDN article Oka has linked. After reading it, _you_ can correct the code.

Answer (score -1):

Your code creates an object and supplies it with 3 "own" properties:

```
var o = {
  name: 'Master',
  number: '117',
  last: 'Chief'
};
```

You then simply create a 4th with:

```
o.prototype = {
  planet: 'Halo'
};
```

When a property is retrieved on an object, the current object's "own" properties are examined first. If no property is found, then the prototype chain is checked - - all the way up to Object.prototype. If the property cannot be found anywhere in the prototype chain, then undefined is returned.

When a property is SET however, a different behavior occurs. Regardless of whether the property was inherited, a new property is created as an "own" property on the current object (an exception to this rule is if the property in question is an accessor property).

The Prototype that you are setting is creating the 4th and final property that you see outputted in the console.